# Ubuntu can't configure proper gateway at boot

Tags: networking, routing

My Ubuntu machine is connected to internet via wifi, and also connected to LAN by ethernet cable. Every time I log on, I have to run these 2 commands in order to set the proper gateway (wlan0 in my case) so that I can access internet.

```
% sudo route del default
% sudo route add default gw 192.168.3.1
```

To automate, I've tried several things that I've found on internet but didn't work so far. Though can't remember all of them, one of them is this:

```
(In /etc/network/interfaces, add the followings and reboot)
up route del default 
up route add -net 192.168.3.0/24 gw 192.168.3.1 dev wlan0
```

The result of route command right after boot (before running the operation shown above, 10.0.* is LAN) shows that eth0 is still set default gw against my desire:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.193.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.3.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
default         10.0.193.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I use Ubuntu 11.04

Has anyone got a direct solution?

---

**Update** 10/22/11) Since I might have changed many configurations, I don't know only these changes are the ones that take effect, but here are my solution. Now the computer allows both internet (wlan0) and local (eth0) on boot.

- (as the chosen answer indicates) Check both "Ignore automatically obtained routes" & "use this connection only for resources on its network"
- Modify /etc/network/interfaces as follows:

  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback
  up route del default 
  up route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 gw 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0

Comment: have you tried altering settings in edit wireless/wired connections after ubuntu starts?

Comment: @IsaacS is this a client or server that you are having an issue with?  If a client - I presume you are asking how to configure Network Manager via its GUI?

Comment: @BlackDivine thx, but I guess I don't know what "edit wireless/wired connections" you mentioned means..

Comment: @fossfreedom thx, I think I should respond as "client". This is what I use as desktop computer with GUI. I don't mind the solution is either via commandline or GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click your network icon
2. Edit connections.
3. Select the first wired connection (eth0)
4. Edit
5. In the IPv4 settings, click Routes.
6. Check the bottom box.

I think that should do it, but I haven't actually tried it myself, so it would be nice with a comfirmation.

Comment: Thanks. If the "bottom box" in the step 6 is "Use this connection only for resources on its network", then unfortunately checking it (and reboot) didn't change the situation as I tried just now.

Comment: I don't use English, so I don't recall exactly what it says. :) Perhaps you can also ignore automatically discovered routes? I seem to remember having done something like that once.

Comment: Thanks again. I checked both checkboxes and rebooted OS but no good.

Comment: as I updated my original question, I somehow solved the issue, based upon your hints. Thanks!